# Spyder or Jupyter? for Qiskit

Tags: jupyter-notebook, spyder, quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm working with Qiskit but I'm a bit confused because I don't know why I should use Jupyter

I tried to install Jupyter but couldn't so now I decided to use Spyder instead. Is there any reason why I should use Jupyter later?

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter Notebooks has several advantages for Qiskit (and for many more):

**Interactive Code Environment:** It provides you with an environment where you can run the code blocks individually, which is crucial in quantum computing

**Visualization:** Jupyter supports in-line visualization, which is useful while using Qiskit.

**Documentation & Sharing:** You can easily create documentation and share it with anyone you wish.

**Qiskit Integration:** Jupyter has good integration with Qiskit and other Python libraries, making it a convenient environment for quantum computing tasks. You can easily install and manage libraries and dependencies within Jupyter.

However, if you're doing more straightforward scripting or prefer a more traditional development environment, Spyder could be a good choice. However, if you are focused on learning, experimenting, or presenting your work related to quantum computing, you might find Jupyter Notebooks more beneficial in the long run.